# Install the content of a folder into another

Tags: shell-script, files, software-installation, file-copy

I'm trying to write a Makefile to install the content of my folder into another on the system.

I would like to keep the same directory structure, like this.

```
localfolder
├── a
└── b
    ├── c
        └── d
            ├── e
                └── f
```

I tried different options, but it does nothing

```
$ install -d localfolder /opt/folder
(does nothing)
$ install -t localfolder /opt/folder
install: omitting directory '/opt/folder'
$ install -D localfolder /opt/folder
install: omitting directory 'localfolder'
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction ? Googling 'linux install command' is not bringing any pertinent information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who wants a solution, here you go:
the install command doesn't work recursivly. So I wrote a shell script that does the trick.

The first argument is the folder you want to copy, and the second is the target directory

```
#!/bin/sh

# Program to use the command install recursivly in a folder

magic_func() {
    echo "entering ${1}"
    echo "target $2"

    for file in $1; do
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
            echo "file : $file"
            echo "installing into $2/$file"
            install -D $file $2/$file

        elif [ -d "$file" ]; then
            echo "directory : $file"
            magic_func "$file/*" "$2"

        else
            echo "not recognized : $file"

        fi
        done
}

magic_func "$1" "$2"
```

It is also available as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Bl4ckb0ne/3a79934492114eb812956dd4ec2bbc7e)

Answer (score 0):

**Source** side of the `install` is files list (according to `info`).  So, use

```
install source/* /destination
```

`-d` and `-D` options create missed directories in the destination (with difference),
`-t` option means that **destination** is the directory.

With directory option it copies each **source file** into **destination folder** with source's file name

Comment: I works for the first layer of directory, but won't go into the folders

Comment: You could use `install source/{file1,file2,file3...} /destination` and select each file to install

Comment: I wrote a shell script to use the install command recursivly https://gist.github.com/Bl4ckb0ne/3a79934492114eb812956dd4ec2bbc7e
Thanks for your help!